# CakePhp use Ajax to load highcharts div content

Tags: html, ajax, cakephp, reload

I have a select field I Want that when I select an option I reload my div chart content using the following ajax function :

```
function function_get_date_graphe(graphe_date){ 
       var date = graphe_date;

       $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: base_url + "/icicpermis/trainers/graph2/"+date,
            data: 'graphe_date='+date, 
            success: function(response) { 
                document.getElementById('piewrapper').innerHTML=response ;

            }

        });
    }
```

AND that's the div I want to reload

```
<div id="piewrapper" style="display: block; float: left; width:90%; margin-bottom: 20px;">

    <?php //echo $chart->render('Pie Chart'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Highcharts->render('Pie Chart'); ?>
    </div>
```

To let you know I am using two functions controller the first one "manager_graph" used to show the defalu chart with default content and the seconde one "graph2" is called by the ajax function to just get the new content . The problem is when I call my ajax function The div is not displayed.

Comment: Ok, and what's the problem (do not write it in a comment please, update your question instead)?

Comment: @ndm done check now

Comment: i would suggest you use jQuery syntax i.e. $('#piewrapper').html()